# How to sort this OrderedDict into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am trying to get these OrderedDicts within "epd:amount" into a pandas Dataframe with 3 columns: '@xmlns:epd'; '@epd:module' ; '#text'. I tried now for some time. Has anyone a good guess?

```
OrderedDict([('epd:amount',
                         [OrderedDict([('@xmlns:epd',
                                        'http://www.iai.kit.edu/EPD/2013'),
                                       ('@epd:module', 'A1'),
                                       ('#text', '0.0')]),
                          OrderedDict([('@xmlns:epd',
                                        'http://www.iai.kit.edu/EPD/2013'),
                                       ('@epd:module', 'A2'),
                                       ('#text', '0.0')]),
                          OrderedDict([('@xmlns:epd',
                                        'http://www.iai.kit.edu/EPD/2013'),
                                       ('@epd:module', 'A3'),
                                       ('#text', '0.927477418791169')]),
                          OrderedDict([('@xmlns:epd',
                                        'http://www.iai.kit.edu/EPD/2013'),
                                       ('@epd:module', 'A1-A3'),
                                       ('#text', '0.927477418791169')]),
                          OrderedDict([('@xmlns:epd',
                                        'http://www.iai.kit.edu/EPD/2013'),
                                       ('@epd:module', 'A5'),
                                       ('#text', '5.83315996933576')]),
                          OrderedDict([('@xmlns:epd',
                                        'http://www.iai.kit.edu/EPD/2013'),
                                       ('@epd:module', 'C2'),
                                       ('#text', '0.0')]),
                          OrderedDict([('@xmlns:epd',
                                        'http://www.iai.kit.edu/EPD/2013'),
                                       ('@epd:module', 'C3'),
                                       ('#text', '0.0')]),
                          OrderedDict([('@xmlns:epd',
                                        'http://www.iai.kit.edu/EPD/2013'),
                                       ('@epd:module', 'D'),
                                       ('@epd:scenario', 'energetisch'),
                                       ('#text', '0.0')]),
                          OrderedDict([('@xmlns:epd',
                                        'http://www.iai.kit.edu/EPD/2013'),
                                       ('@epd:module', 'D'),
                                       ('@epd:scenario', 'stofflich'),
                                       ('#text', '0.0')])])
```

Comment: It is important to demonstrate to the community that you are *also* working to solve your question. What have you tried so far? The best way to show  that would be to include the **text** version of your code attempt. if the data above was to be stored in a variable "foo", what does `pandas.DataFrame(foo['epd:amount'])` give you?

Comment: I will do in the future. This was Life Cycle Analysis data and it shows values of co2 emissions in different life stages of glass material. I will give more context in the future. Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a dictionary, so you can get a value by key, then convert it to the dataframe. I've removed some of your data for simplicity.

```
import pandas as pd
from  collections import OrderedDict

x = OrderedDict([('epd:amount',
                         [OrderedDict([('@xmlns:epd',
                                        'http://www.iai.kit.edu/EPD/2013'),
                                       ('@epd:module', 'A1'),
                                       ('#text', '0.0')]),
                          OrderedDict([('@xmlns:epd',
                                        'http://www.iai.kit.edu/EPD/2013'),
                                       ('@epd:module', 'D'),
                                       ('@epd:scenario', 'stofflich'),
                                       ('#text', '0.0')])])])

df = pd.DataFrame(data['epd:amount'])
```

Comment: No problem, very interesting data!